# How to sort a year into 365 days with index [0,1,2,...23] and conver to dict

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, indexing

I'm having some trouble arranging data from df, so I can get data in a list where the indexes goes from 0 to 23 for each day.

```
timeStart = pd.to_datetime(dt.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
timeEnd = pd.to_datetime(dt.datetime(2021, 12, 31, 23, 0, 0))
df = df.loc[(df['HourUTC'] >= timeStart) & (df['HourUTC'] <= timeEnd)]

dataList = df['SpotPriceDKK']/1000
#Rewriting the dataframe from a list to dictionary
dataDict = dataList.to_dict()
```

I want a list that look like (actually a dictionary), it takes the values from 0 to 23 each day and list them with the indexes [0,1,2,3...23] for each day. Instead I right now get following

```
output:
dataList
Out[140]: 
61314    0.18119
61307    0.17844
61300    0.17650
61293    0.17657
61286    0.17903
  
29       0.25253
22       0.24599
15       0.24049
8        0.22130
1        0.34654
```

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t exactly understand your problem but maybe this could help. It writes all hours of a year and reset the index at 00:00.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in pd.date_range('2022-1-1 00:00:00', periods=356, freq='D'):
    date_day = pd.Series(pd.date_range(f'{i} 00:00:00', periods=24, freq='H'))
    df = pd.concat([df, date_day], ignore_index = False )



df.to_csv('test.csv')
```